# How to access the Window when not an activity?

Tags: android, get, window, screen, brightness

I want to access the Window class so I can set the screen brightness on my phone. The problem is that the class I want to do  this from is not an activity. Is it possible to do this without being an activity? I have a context and a content resolver, if that helps.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try `((Activity)mContext).getWindow()`?  You may want to include a check that `mContext` actually is an `Activity` (or handle the exception) because not all `Context`s are `Activity`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options here.

1. Start a new transparent `Activity`, adjust the brightness value (of both the `Window` and system settings), then call `finish()` on the `Activity`. This will steal focus from the user in some cases, no matter what flags you use.
2. Create a persistent transparent system-wide overlay using a `Dialog` and the flag `WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY`. This can cause odd issues like blocking the installation of apps.

In other words, there's no clean way of doing it.